# Laravel - Convert database integer to an associated string

Tags: laravel-4

I have my users table with a column named `status`. In this column I just store a number, based off their status, 1 - admin, 2 - owner, etc. I know that I can display these values with `{{ users->status }}`, but only shows the stored number. How can I show the actual name instead of the stored number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Eloquent Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators).

Define an array of statuses and use the status number from your database as a key to change the value in the model so that in the view `{{ $users->status }}` equals `admin`

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $statuses = array(
        '1' => 'admin',
        '2' => 'owner'
    );

    public function getStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->statuses[$value];
    }

}
```

- `getStatusAttribute` converts `1` to `admin` when retrieving a record.

---

You could also have a `set` method for when records are stored in the model.

**In View** `{{ $user->status }} // echos 'admin'`